# Dimension of Invariant Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let V be a real or complex finite dimensional vector space, and let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$. Prove that $V$ has a $T$-invariant subspace of dimension 1 or 2.

I figured out one way to prove this: If $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $T$, $p$ factors as a product of distinct linear factors or irreducible quadratic factors. So $T$ has an eigenvector ($\implies$ 1-dimensional invariant subspace) or $\exists v\in V$ such that $(x^2+ax+b)v=0$. In that case, $\{v,Tv\}$ is invariant and has dimensional at most 2.

I was wondering if there is another way to see this using the primary or cyclic decomposition. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose you need to assume also that $V$ is not a trivial vector space. You would need to show that the vector $v$ is not zero vector, or else $\{v,Tv\}$ could be zero-dimensional.

Comment: @edm Yes, assuming $V\not= \{0\}$